# SAPUI5: Combining OData with other Webservice in the same table

Tags: javascript, json, sapui5

this question is about developing SAPUI5 with the SAP Web IDE. I want to combine a OData-Service with a web-service that I just call via POST Method. So basically it's like that:
I retrieve a list from the OData Service (which is from a backend-SAP system) and show this in a table element. So far so good. It works.

Now for each row in the table I want to call a webservice with POST method to retrieve a value which I want to show in the row as well. Like:

Row Column 1 has value A and column 2 has value B and I pass this to the webservice which tells me "For A and B the result is X". So I want to show X in another column of the same row.

How can this be achieved? Is there any example you know of?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a JSON model with the data in your AJAX POST response. Bind the cell you want in your table to this new JSON model. Then if you want to make select data in your JSON model depending on the value you receive from the OData for each specific row, then use a formatter function using parts.

Here a example getting data from Northwind and a JSON model with fake data: https://jsbin.com/racenaqoki/edit?html,output

With a real AJAX call:
https://jsbin.com/jivomamuvi/edit?html,output

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title>MVC with XmlView</title>

    <!-- Load UI5, select "blue crystal" theme and the "sap.m" control library -->
    <script id='sap-ui-bootstrap'
        src='https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js'
        data-sap-ui-theme='sap_bluecrystal'
        data-sap-ui-libs='sap.m'
        data-sap-ui-xx-bindingSyntax='complex'></script>


    <!-- DEFINE RE-USE COMPONENTS - NORMALLY DONE IN SEPARATE FILES -->

    <!-- define a new (simple) View type as an XmlView
     - using data binding for the Button text
     - binding a controller method to the Button's "press" event
     - also mixing in some plain HTML
     note: typically this would be a standalone file -->

    <script id="view1" type="sapui5/xmlview">
    <mvc:View xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" controllerName="my.own.controller">
        <Page>
        <Table items="{/Orders}" updateFinished="onTableUpdateFinished">
      <columns>
          <Column >
              <Text text="My Value From OData"/>
          </Column>
          <Column>
              <Text text="My Value From AJAX"/>
          </Column>
      </columns>
      <items>
          <ColumnListItem>
            <cells>
              <ObjectIdentifier title="{CustomerID}"/>
              <ObjectIdentifier text="{parts:[{path:'CustomerID'}, {path:'myOtherModel>/'}], formatter: '.myFormatter'}"/>
            </cells>
        </ColumnListItem>
      </items>
    </Table>
        </Page>
    </mvc:View> 
</script>


    <script>
        // define a new (simple) Controller type
        sap.ui.controller("my.own.controller", {
          onInit: function(){
              var myOtherModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
              this.getView().setModel(myOtherModel, "myOtherModel");

              //Here your AJAX call to get the data from a POST request
              /*
                $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: url,
          data: data,
          success: this.ajaxSuccess,
          dataType: dataType
        });
              */

              //Let's simulate that there was a success receiving the following data
              var data = {
                VINET: {
                  message: "VINET Rocks!!"
                },
                WARTH: {
                  message: "WARTH is good company!!"
                },
                RICSU: {
                  message: "RICSU I don't like"
                },
                HANAR: {
                  message: "HANAR was my first customer"
                }
              }
              this.ajaxSuccess(data);
            },

            ajaxSuccess: function(data){
              this.getView().getModel("myOtherModel").setData(data)
            },

            myFormatter: function(sCustomerID, otherModelData){
              // This formatter will be executed for each table row. 
              // In the first parameter, the value binded in the first column
              // In the second parameter, the node you want of your second model (in this case the root node)

              //do whatever you want here and return a string for the 'text' property in this case
              if(otherModelData[sCustomerID]){
                // If there is a node in your second model with a node for the given Customer ID, then return the message into it
                return otherModelData[sCustomerID].message;
              }
              //Otherwise return empty string
              return "";
            }
        });



        /*** THIS IS THE "APPLICATION" CODE ***/
        // create a Model and assign it to the View
        // Using here the HEROKU Proxy to avoid a CORS issue
        var uri = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/services.odata.org/Northwind/Northwind.svc"; // local proxy for cross-domain access
        var oNorthwindModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel(uri, {
            maxDataServiceVersion: "2.0"
        }); 
        // instantiate the View
        var myView = sap.ui.xmlview({viewContent:jQuery('#view1').html()}); // accessing the HTML inside the script tag above
        // Set the OData Model
        myView.setModel(oNorthwindModel);


        myView.placeAt('content');
    </script>

</head>
<body id='content' class='sapUiBody'>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you for the very useful example. I [built upon your model](https://jsbin.com/feyuvoh/edit?html,output) and I can call my service (webserver confirms with 200). However, I'm not able to pass any data to it (I believe it would be in the `data` section of the ajax call) and I also don't know how to retrieve the data so that it can be passed on. I admit I miss solid JS skills. If I use `alert(response);` in the success section I can see the data coming back from the webservice.

Comment: I've just saw your snippet. I've just changed it. be sure that you bind the context for the AJAX success event. `this.ajaxSuccess.bind(this)` and comment the line after the fake data when I hardcoded the function call `//this.ajaxSuccess(data);`

Comment: I am receiving a 404 in your fake service, I guess because I'm out of your network. But I've test it with 'jsonplaceholder.typicode.com' and it works. Take a look here: https://jsbin.com/jivomamuvi/edit?html,output

Comment: So finally I got it working, thanks to your support! I learnt a lot about Ajax and JS. However, in the way it's called currently it' s a one-time call when the table is created. It should be a call per row (ignore the performance topic for the moment please). Can this also be achieved?

Comment: In your columnListItem, you can use a event called 'modelContextChange' [here the docu](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api//symbols/sap.ui.base.ManagedObject.html#event:modelContextChange) set a handler for this event and fire your Ajax calls there (I've no snippet this time, I'm with my phone)

Comment: I think maybe better than 'modelContextChange' could be 'updateFinished' and 'updateStarted' events, also available in the sap.m.Table

Answer (score -1):

You could extend your oData service so that entity would contain the "webservice_result" property. In Data Provider Class you would leave out that property empty and only return your "A" and "B" values.

After you call your oData service and get the results back, you would then just call your other webservice using ajax with values A, B and when you get the result, you would just set "webservice_result" property of given row (entity) with the returned value using 
`oDataModel.setProperty("row_x/webservice_result", value)`

See:

[jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

[setProperty method](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.44.23/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel.html#setProperty)

Comment: In my opinion, this should be really a last resort solution, as it implies changing the structure of the OData service to contain artificial attributes used solely on the UI for storing results from another REST service. This basically couples the OData and the REST service / UI (which is never a good idea IMO). Also, the setProperty method should mostly be used for updating the entity, using it for storing transient results is a error-prone miss-usage of the API (e.g. you could accidentally trigger an update on the entity).

Comment: Of course, that depends on the use case. But, if he only wanted to have a read-only report with values from different sources it would be easy to set up with well-thought single entity and a Smart Table on the UI5 side.